# Joomla 3.x "Error Check-out failed with the following error:" with no more info

Tags: php, joomla

I've written a bunch of custom components and only one of them has the following problem.  When I click on an individual row in the admin list to edit it, I get the infamous:

> "Error Check-out failed with the following error:"

Now, sure, we've all had this error in Joomla, however, there's usually more information with it, such as, I don't know, AN ERROR???  I've turned up the error level to the max, searched the PHP logs, set the Debug System on and still there's nothing to be found.  It's worth noting that the "error" doesn't really stop me from accomplishing the edit, except for the fact that when I click Save & Close the data is saved though the page flow doesn't return to the admin list.  I have to click the Cancel/Close button to go back.

I created this and other working components using Component Creator I override none of the table methods and only the save method in the model.

Also worth noting is that I did a Global Check-In as well as scoured the database for any related checked out values and found none.  I think the "Check-out" is a red herring.

Any ideas on how to debug this issue further are welcome.

Regards,
Rob

Comment: NOTE: I "moved" this to http://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/9864/joomla-3-x-error-check-out-failed-with-the-following-error-with-no-more-info 
since that's Joomla specific.  Since StackOverflow and StackExchange seem to be intertwined I was going to delete this question here however the message that appeared when I chose to delete was rather ominous, so I left it here...

Answer (score 0):

You can turn debugging on by setting in joomla system in following way:

```
1.go top menu "system"
2.Select global configuration
3.go to gebug setting
4.turn on system debug
```

I hope by doing this you can see proper error message!!

Comment: As the well-used saying goes "Been there, done that."  Sorry, I forgot to mention that in my original message.  I've edited it to reflect that.